# OSC proper fader control algorithm

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi, osc

I am coding in python 2.7 to accommodate OSC communication from my ipad to my rasp pi using the 'touchOSC' app from the app store. (this is not for music or midi, but simply to access values to control stepper motors etc..) I am using windows to code and then I transfer the .py to my rasp pi (not the issue here). I set up the fader in touch OSC's layout software with the name, IP address that is in the code below. Also, I set the range value of the fader in the software that touchOSC has provided from 0 to 1.

The issue is that I am receiving only zeros when I invoke the fader on my ipad. What I wish to see is the values incrementing from 0 to 1 by floating values. I believe I would need to use some sort range function? This is the issue, How can specify that I want the fader to increment in the code below?

Right now the code is:

```
from OSC import OSCServer,OSCClient, OSCMessage

server = OSCServer( ("192.168.0.8", 8000) ) 
client = OSCClient()

def handle_timeout(self):
    print ("I'm IDLE")
#This here is just to do something while the script recieves no information....
server.handle_timeout = types.MethodType(handle_timeout, server)

def fader_0(path, tags, args, source): 
    value=int(args[0]) # Value is the variable that will transform the input from the faders into whole numbers(easier to deal with)
    print "Fader Value:", value

server.addMsgHandler("/1/fader1", fader)
```

My question regards the `Def fader_0(path, tags, args, source)`
When I input: `value = int(args[0])`, I receive a zero when I adjust the fader on my ipad via touch OSC. this is obvious; however, I wish to access the floating points in between 0 and 1 as the fader is incremented.

I assume the code would be: value = `float(args[someLoop])` maybe something like `value = float(args[range(0,1,.125)])`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `range` doesn't work with float steps. What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: yes, you are right. I simply want to edit the line of code so that instead of sending a zero when I invoke the fader, a list of float values is sent that corresponding to the increase of the fader. Maybe it would be a while loop? `while True. if args < 1. value += 0.125. else: break. print value`

Comment: I'm not so sure this is a duplicate since it is a controlled increment. My question is how can I increment the value via the slider? I am wondering if a while loop will do this or if there is a better way like using a counter. I apologize, but I don't have much expertise in sending these types of communication via OSC.

Answer (score 0):

The values coming from TouchOSC are floats between 0 and 1. In the `fader_0` function, you currently transform the float from TouchOSC, `args[0]` to an `int` which rounds any number less than 1 down to 0, thus your program prints out zero every time.

You can easy see how this happens in the python interpreter:

```
In [2]: int(0.7)
Out[2]: 0
```

The solution is just to remove the `int` function from `fader_0` like so:

```
def fader_0(path, tags, args, source): 
    value=args[0]
    print "Fader Value:", value
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for a linear interpolation function. You can have TouchOSC translate the float value to discrete values before sending.

To do this use a function that maps a value from 0 to 1 to a range that you want like this:

```lua
function lerp(min, max, percent)
  return math.floor(min + (max - min) * percent)
end
```

Where

- `min` is smallest value you want sent
- `max` is the largest value you want sent
- `percent` is a value between 0 and 1

For example `lerp(1, 128, someFloat)`

### Coding it in TouchOSC

Since we want to modify the value before sending, we will need to define the controller's `onValueChanged` callback, which is called whenever the controller is moved.

Keep in mind that TouchOSC [doesn't automatically distinguish number types when it sends over OSC](https://hexler.net/touchosc/manual/script-functions-global#simple-osc-messages) so to send an integer you must use the argument type tags format.

Putting that all together, this is what the script for your control could look like. In this example you would send values from 1 to 256, though you can use whatever range you want:

```lua
function lerp(min, max, percent)
  return math.floor(min + (max - min) * percent)
end

function onValueChanged(key)
    if key == 'x' then
      local scaled = lerp(1, 256, self.values['x'])
      sendOSC({
        '/1/fader1', 
        {
            { tag = 'i', value = scaled }
        }
      });
    end
end
```